# Unknown error is catched

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

First page of my application is Login page. When I type id/pw, my app should move to home page but it throws an error like screenshot below. It seems like it occurs when react-navigation tries to forward to the next page.

One weird thing is that when I set 'Debug JS Remotely', this error doesn't show up and the application works fine.

Anybody has a clue?

[image]

Comment: [2853](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2853) [2862](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2862)

Comment: thank you. I found a solution from the links